# How do you create a new Microsoft DNS zone with powershell that loads from a DNS file?

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm trying to use Powershell to create some DNS zones on a Microsoft DNS server.  We have the DNS files already created and fully populated.  The idea is that we place those DNS files in the `\dns` directory, and then run the script to import them. The problem I am having is that when I run the command below, it overwrites the populated DNS file with a new (empty) zone/file.

`Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name abc.com -ZoneFile "abc.com.dns"`

How do I do this, please?

Comment: `"...it overwrites the populated DNS file with a new (empty) zone/file."` --- Because that is what that cmdlet is for. As per the help file definition `[The Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone cmdlet adds a specified primary zone on a Domain Name System (DNS) server.]`, adds, not updates or appends. Never ever run destructive code (Add, delete/remove, update/modify, etc.) without validation first. Leverage `[-WhatIf / -Confirm]`. To see what is happening, use the `Trace-Command` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the file and create the DNS Zone using

```
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name abc.com -ZoneFile "abc.com.dns"
```

can you then add the A Records using

```
$entries = Import-Csv <filename with DNS Records>
foreach($entry in $entries){
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name $entry.name -ZoneName abc.com -IPv4Address $entry.ip -ComputerName $entry.HostName 
}
```

There are also a bunch of other ADD commands for other record types, so you maybe able to build a script to identify the type from the input depending on the contents

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecorda?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dnscmd` to easily accomplish that.

```
dnscmd /zoneadd test.com /primary /file test.com.dns /load
```

The zone file has to be in C:\Windows\System32\dns.

As far as I know there is no specific Powershell module for importing DNS zones. You can verify that with `Get-Command -Module DnsServer -Noun *Zone*`.